# python add an id for each element in list

Tags: python, list

I want to add an id for each element, if the elements occur multiple times, it should be added with the id when it occurs the first time, I have no idea for this problem, could anyone help me

input:

```
omg = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 1]
```

output:

```
omg_id = [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Little tricky solution to obtain ids in order of occurrence, using a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

omg = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 1]
d = defaultdict(lambda: len(d))  # late binding allows d not to be defined yet
omg_id = [d[x] for x in omg]
# [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3]
```

The default factory assigns the current number of known keys to every new key. Since key access not only returns but also assigns the value, the `defaultdict` "grows" during the comprehension.

Comment: Interesting use of `defaultdict` +1 !

Comment: @jpp Yes, I was quite delighted when I first found out that the factory function could self-reference the (not yet existing) instance. That makes all kind of concise magic possible :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use iteration with a dictionary to construct a mapping. Then apply this mapping to your original list.

```
omg = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a', 'b', 1]

d = {}
for i in omg:
    if i not in d:
        d[i] = len(d)

omg_id = list(map(d.get, omg))

print(omg_id)

[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3]
```

Here's an alternative solution using `toolz.unique` [equivalent to the `unique_everseen` recipe in the `itertools` docs]:

```
from toolz import unique

d = {v: k for k, v in enumerate(unique(omg))}
omg_id = list(map(d.get, omg))
```

Both solutions have the following features:

- O(n) complexity.
- Require elements of `omg` to be hashable.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
from more_itertools import unique_everseen
t=dict([(e,c) for c,e in enumerate(unique_everseen(omg))])
print([t.get(e) for e in omg])
```

Answer (score 1):

Order dict will remove duplicate and remain the order. You can also do it in one shot with following:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

omg_id=[{v:k for k,v in enumerate(OrderedDict.fromkeys(omg))}[num] for num in omg]
```

result:

```
[0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a set with items from the list. Enumerate the set and create a dictionary with key to enumeration values. Then use the list and the dictionary to produce the desired output.